# SocketException: Connection reset when serializing

Tags: java, networking, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a basic TCP connection where i send an object from client to server through *serialization*. But i'm getting an error when performing this simple task, below is the code:

Client:

```
public client() throws IOException{
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4390);
    System.out.println("Client connected with server");
    
    Student student = new Student(1, "jemoi", "lerry");
    
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(student);
}
```

Server:

```
public server() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4390);
    
    System.out.println("Server initialized successfully");
    
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Student student = (Student)ois.readObject();
    
    System.out.println("Object send from client: " + student.getFirstName());
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The error occurs at line:

```
Student student = (Student)ois.readObject();
```

Comment: What language is this - Java?

Comment: If you added the right tags to your question, it would be seen sooner by people who are experts in the subject. I've added the Java tag

Comment: if you don't agree with the edit you're free to roll it back

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I forgot to set the close() from ObjectOutputStream in client.